# xpath not work correctly

Tags: java, xpath

XPATH : `//requestHeader//*[local-name()='clientUsername']`

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:req="http://www.ABC.com/ws/requestHeader"
  xmlns:web="http://com/ABC/XXX/YYY">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <web:isServiceUp>
      <web:requestHeader>
        <req:clientUsername>GENT</req:clientUsername>
        <req:languageCode>?</req:languageCode>
      </web:requestHeader>
    </web:isServiceUp>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It suppose to be return GENT but It returns empty string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the following:

```
//web:requestHeader//*[local-name()='clientUsername']
```

You need to look for `web:requestHeader` and not just `requestHeader`:

You can test this out [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/c3daea089408a31b59cadbeee13d4cf8). Try it with just `requestHeader` and you'll see that it returns nothing. When you change it to `web:requestHeader`, you will get the element that you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
//web:requestHeader/req:clientUsername
```

Answer (score 1):

The `requestHeader` element is in the `http://com/ABC/XXX/YYY` namespace, so `//requestHeader` will not find it (that XPath is looking for an element named `requestHeader` in *no* namespace).  You either need to do the same `local-name()` trick you're doing with `clientUsername` or set up the appropriate prefix binding using whatever mechanism your XPath library provides, and then use that prefix in the expression.

You've tagged your question "java" so if you're using `javax.xml.xpath` you need to look up the [`setNamespaceContext` method on `XPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html#setNamespaceContext%28javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext%29).